# Defining area for QuickOSM query in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I would like to use the QGIS Modeler to collect all objects of as OSM feature within polygons in a layer. The QuickOSM algorithm has a function called "build query inside an area" and I was hoping I could select my polygon layer here but that doesn't work (see picture below, "Inside the area").

Does anyone have an idea how to use this algorithm or if it is possible at all to select within polygons?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with the provider of the plugin, whether there are similar bug reports, or if there's a tutorial how to use the plugin inside a model?

Comment: The user guide for the plugin is quite helpful. For me, the key breakthrough was to use the 'Open OSM File' Processing model. See the user guide: 
https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/user-guide/processing/